# Can I limit autofill to cell contents only?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro which uses `Range.AutoFill`. Surprisingly it autofilled form controls, too.

```
Public Sub onetwobucklemyshoe()
With Sheet1
.Range("a1:a2").AutoFill .Range("a1:a10"), xlFillValues
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Is there a way to stop it doing this (I assumed `xlFillValues` would be enough). Otherwise I can do it with a for-loop in VBA but it seems wasteful.

Version: Excel Office 365 16.0.12325.20280 / Windows 10.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the control `Object positioning` property in "Don't move or size with cells"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set form control properties to `Don't move size with cell.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put this part at the beginning of your code...

```
Sub testMakeSh()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  MakeShapeFloating sh
End Sub
```

And place the next function somewhere in your module:

```
Sub MakeShapeFloating(sh As Worksheet)
 Dim s As Shape
  For Each s In sh.Shapes
     s.Placement = xlFreeFloating
  Next
End Sub
```